# Windows WLS Ubuntu - Trying to execute a ruby script that utilizes bin/bash results in "No such file or directory", won't detect sub-directories

Tags: ruby, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to execute a Ruby script:

```
/home/user/git_repo/bin/script.rb
```

Which always returns something like:

```
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: /home/user/git_repo: No such file or directory
```

However, if I change the directory within the code to be just /home/, the code executes perfectly and I don't get the error (but it fails because /home/ isn't a git repo)

My question is, how come /home/ works fine and bin/bash is able to recognise that (and other main dirs. like /etc/) but it can't find my /home/user/ directory?

If I manually cd to that directory it works as expected, and using ls -F /home/ returns:

user/ and linuxbrew/

So as far as I'm aware, everything is set up correctly, I just don't understand how the script can detect the /home/ directory but not the /user/ directory within that, thanks!

Comment: Just to add more detail, doing: /bin/bash -c "cd /home/user/git_repo" works fine

Comment: Line endings? Try `dos2unix script.rb` to remove carriage returns.

Comment: could you share the contents of _script.rb_ please?